# Dynamically created child component need to access parent function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have 3 TS files as below: 1) Parent-Component.ts 2) Child-Component.ts 3) Service.ts

We have a button click event in Parent-Component.ts which call the function in Service.ts and this function create the Child Component Dynamically as code given below.

**Parent-Component.html:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="mt-3 col-md-12">
<h3>{{ i18n.common + 'Filter' | dynamicTranslate }}</h3>
<div #filterCriteria></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row filter-actions mb-3">
<div class="col-md-12">
<button type="button" **(click)="appendAdditionalFilter()" **>
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>     <strong>&nbsp;{{ 'Add Filter' }}</strong>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-2" 
(click)="appendFilterFromService()">{{ i18n.common + 'Apply Filter' | dynamicTranslate }}
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

when Add Filter is clicked function appendAdditionalFilter() is called from Parent-Component.ts  which call Service.ts to create child component dynamically.

**Parent-Component.ts:**

```
@ViewChild('filterCriteria', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false})
filterCriteriaContainer: ViewContainerRef;
appendAdditionalFilter() {    
this.filterCriteriaContainer = this.filterGridService
.addFilter(this.filterCriteriaContainer, this.MetaData, this.i18n.Test1, 
this.Test2);
}
```

**Service.ts:**

```
addFilter(
filterCriteriaContainer: ViewContainerRef,
MetaData: Array<FieldMetaDataDto>,
Test1: string,
Test2?: number,
filter?: FilterDto,
): ViewContainerRef {
const comp = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
const filterCriteria = filterCriteriaContainer.createComponent(comp);

filterCriteria.instance.ref = filterCriteria;

filterCriteria.instance.translationKeyBase = Test1;

filterCriteria.instance.filterMetadata = MetaData;
filterCriteria.instance.dataTarget = Test2;
  
return filterCriteriaContainer;
}
```

Now we have a Remove button click event on Child Component which would need to call function appendFilterFromService() in Parent-Component.ts.

**Child-Component.html:**

```
<div>
<button (click)="remove()" type="button" class="btn btn-action btn-small">
<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
</button>
<strong>{{i18n.common + 'Remove Filter' | dynamicTranslate }} </strong>
</div>
```

**Child-Component.ts:**

```
ref: ComponentRef<ChildComponent>;
remove(){
this.ref.destroy();
//Need to call Parent-Component.ts function appendFilterFromService() here//
}
```

**Any Help would be appreciated.**

Comment: inject the service into both parent and child component?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on it .. as how should i go about it ??

Answer (score 1):

Since your service is expecting few other parameters from the parent component, one possible way would be to raise an event from child component which will be captured in the parent.

Your child component should have an `@Output` binding like this:

```
  @Output() removeEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

in child's html the usual `click` binding for "Remove" button:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onRemove()">Remove</button>
```

the line which will emit the event in `onRemove` event handler:

```
  onRemove(): void {
    this.removeEvent.emit('remove');
  }
```

parent's html should look like this to specify which method should be called once a child component is emitting an event:

```
  <app-child (removeEvent)="onRemoveFromChild($event)"> </app-child>
```

then you are now in parent component triggering the whole flow from child component:

```
  onRemoveFromChild(event: string): void {  
    this.appendAdditionalFilter();
  }
```

Simplified [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-znajme?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts) for reference.

**Update**

In case of a dynamic component once you create it you will get back a reference, something like this:

```
const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(ChildComponent);
```

Using that reference you can acccess the "instance" and on that the event with `@Output` something like this:

```
componentRef.instance.removeEvent.subscribe((event: string) => {
  this.service.addFilter();
});
```

Make sure to unsubscribe from these events once component is destroyed.

Forked new [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhtsal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your response .. but the child is created dynamically , so how can i put (removeEvent) dynamically in child <app-child (removeEvent)="onRemoveFromChild($event)"> </app-child>.

Comment: @Devendrajadhav apologies, I updated my answer to include the scenario where a child component is created dynamically

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert .. this has worked for me. You are awesome..!!